# How can I update @jupyterlab/application dependency?

Tags: jupyter

I'm using [data science](https://hub.docker.com/r/jupyter/datascience-notebook/) notebook docker image to hose my jupyter lab. However, whenever I want to install a new extension, it will tell me my dependencies are out dated.

Here is the detail:

```
"@jupyterlab/xkcd-extension@0.6.0" is not compatible with the current JupyterLab
Conflicting Dependencies:
JupyterLab              Extension        Package
>=0.18.2 <0.19.0        >=0.19.1 <0.20.0 @jupyterlab/application
>=0.18.2 <0.19.0        >=0.19.1 <0.20.0 @jupyterlab/apputils
```

I've been searching up in jupyterlab issue pool almost for a whole afternoon and still haven't figured. Any help would be great!